# Microsoft word - numbering list - huge indent in list

Tags: microsoft-word

I opened a document I did not create and in the middle of editing it I tried to add a normal numbering list but for some reason it has a huge indent.

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0):

I reckon you can right click on the numbering and change the indent, see screenshots attached.

I'm not sure what it is called in English, but I hope it helps!

---

Edit:
Alternatively look it up here, also for multi level lists:
[How to customise numbered list alignment in Word](https://www.thetraininglady.com/customise-numbered-list-alignment-word/)

[Right click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pexX.png)
[Edit indent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRlA2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found all setting you suggested and setted everything i could to the minimum amount just to see if something helps, but i did nothing for me.

[Define multilevel list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z4AP.png)

[Paragraphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqNyr.png)

[Tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v3AN.png)

[Numering after all changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ5zq.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you use automatic paragraph numbering or bullets read [Shauna Kelly's articles on numbering and bullets](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html). Start with How to create numbered headings or outline numbering in Word 2007 and Word 2010 For large documents you must follow these directions or you will lose your hair!
(Mac version: https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2016/06/outline-numbering-in-word-for-os-x/)

This may seem a bit convoluted at first, but it really is not. Just follow the steps. Shauna Kelly's instructions use the built-in heading styles, but you can use any existing paragraph styles including your custom styles. There are, however advantages to using the built-in heading styles when you create a Table of Contents. Here are some more advantages: [Why Use Word's Built-In Heading Styles?](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/10HeadingStyles.htm) by Shauna Kelly Note, you can modify these built-in styles to look exactly the way you want.

Videos on this

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=He_ob8ydc9E
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qbyTcWo52G4
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GevZOS-nCuw
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niD6VXPvAyU

The basic idea is that the numbering is set using the Define MultiLevel List dialog with each numbering level being attached to an existing paragraph style. Once you have this set up, **you should not use the buttons for numbering in the Ribbon** but rather apply the appropriate style for that level.

You can save a document with this as a template for future documents if you want so you will not need to do this every time.